# Protecting Local SQLite Database (Android Application)

Tags: android, sqlite, security, xamarin.android

We have an Android application which stores its data in a local SQLite database; primarily for performance, but also to allow for working off-line (as we are often in areas with low signal).

At the moment, the data is stored in encrypted format (passed down from our web servers), but this in itself causes a performance issue, where for example, if we want to search records for a particular "surname", we need to decrypt ALL of the data, rather than using a straight SQL query, to include **where surname='Smith'**

We cannot (as it currently stands) store the data in a more friendly 'open-format', as it's possible to 'root' the device, take a copy of the MySQL database, open it and read the data.

Is there the means (perhaps someone can provide an example) to either password protect the local SQLite database or somehow apply encryption, so that we can (from an application perspective) have the database available in open format, but so that if any would-be hacker got hold of the device and rooted it ... they would have a hard time reading our data?

I have searched for a suitable solution and cannot find any options for the SQLite database, any 3rd party software or any examples of code that do this.

Comment: Apologies; should have stated SQLite

Comment: Instead of decrypting the whole db i think matching the encrypted surname will also work

Comment: The problem is that you will still need the encryption key. And this key would have to be stored off-app, be available on-demand (when a user queries his db), and is not cached, otherwise it'd be pointless. But such requirement will go against your requirement that the app's db should be accessible off-line.

Comment: How are you protecting the decryption key currently?

Comment: The key is formed dynamically based off (amongst a couple of other things) user details so that the data is encrypted on a per-user basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SqlCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/), this will might work in your case

Comment: We're looking into this, as it certainly looks like it's what we need. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remote Storage:

Your data is sensitive and needs to be accessed by the user on the go from different devices. If your app is a good one then the above line will hold true.

Security + Remote access from any device says you maintain your dB on a remote server.

Your flow can be :

User login --> Token --> Auth Token in every call --> Process request and get/put data in/from dB

Local Storage:

Let's say that you only want to store data locally and don't want to store it on the server. For this you can use public-key cryptography

You can use a public Key in your app to encrypt the data and store it. Now, you want to access the data. Request the private key from the server and decrypt it.

Again, to get access to private key you should use some form of authorization (or anyone can access your key).

Without the private key, even if a hacker roots the phone and gets his/her hands on the dB, the data would be useless.